# how to do 3d menu in css 3 with that effect like on page

Tags: html, css, menu, 3d

How to do 3d menu in css3 with effect like on tis page

http://www.nautilusplus.com/

Please help really I cant search any tutorials how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example called 'css3 flipping cube' (http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-flipping-cube). This seems to be the effect you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You would use rotateX in CSS3 with an offset origin. The subject your looking for is "3D transfoms "

Answer (score 0):

May this could really help you:

Check out :

3d rotate : http://jqueryplugin.net/3d-drop-mega-menu-using-pure-css/

3d flip down when clicked : http://jqueryplugin.net/css3-3d-flip-menu-javascript/